# Nifi Spark Integration without using Kafka with Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-nifi

I want to read data directly from Nifi OutPort to Spark streaming using PySpark (without using Kafka in between). I have seen few reference code in Scala, there using "SiteToSiteClient" method to setup connection with Nifi. But I am not able to get any equivalent Python module to develop similar code in Python.

Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to implement your own version of the SiteToSiteClient in Python.

NiFi provides the Java implementation:

https://github.com/apache/nifi/tree/master/nifi-commons/nifi-site-to-site-client